# Is it possible to use "set -e" but allow certain commands to fail?

Tags: bash, sh, zsh

I am working on a backup script and would like to stop the script on error except for certain commands such as `veracrypt --mount` which returns 1 when already mounted.

```sh
#! /bin/sh

set -e

veracrypt --text --mount --pim 0 --keyfiles "" --protect-hidden no "/Volumes/Samsung BAR/.b" /Volumes/Backup

borg check /Volumes/Backup/Borg

veracrypt --text --dismount "$BACKUP_VOLUME_PATH"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `||` to execute something that *won't* fail if a primary command fails, such as with:

```
blah || true
{ yada; yada; yada; } || true
```

Without the `|| true`, the script will complain on error then stop. With it, you'll still see the error but the script will carry on.

---

Another possibility is taking advantage of the fact that it's not considered a failure if it's part of an `if`:

```
if blah ; then true ; fi
```

Even if `blah` errors, the script will carry on.

---

Finally, you can turn it off *temporarily* for a specific command:

```
set +e ; blah ; set -e
```

This solution is only really workable if you already know  the current setting. You probably *don't* want to turn on `-e` unless it was set before you turned it off.

To *detect* its current setting and only turn it back on if it was already on beforehand, you can use:

```
# 1: State here can be either +e or -e. If -e, record that fact and make +e.

eWasSet=false; [[ $- = *e* ]] && eWasSet=true && set +e

# 2: Do stuff that needs +e.

blah blah blah

# 3: Revert state if needed. After this, it's as it was in comment 1 above.

${eWasSet} && set -e
```

This works because `$-` contains all of the current `set` values (like `ehB` for error exit, hashing, and brace expansion), so you can use the wildcard equality operators to find out if a particular setting (like `e`) is active.

Comment: It's also possible to `set +e` to disable exit on fail, then re-enable with `set -e`. Useful when several commands follow.

Comment: Another method using a block : `{ foo ; bar ; baz ;} || true`

Comment: @EdouardThiel Interesting! Somehow I thought `set -e` had to be set at the top of a script and couldn’t be toggled afterwards.